# How to Parse Date in java

Tags: java, date

```
Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 03 16:59:51 IST 2018" Exception

String date="Tue Jul 03 16:59:51 IST 2018";
```

i want to parse it.
My code is

```
SimpleDateFormat newformat=SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
Date d=newformat.parse(date);
```

Comment: hum, you do you expect your pattern to parse your string ? it's just impossible, string is *Day Month year*, and pattern is *year-month-day*, you should learn to build pattern

Comment: Your pattern has to match the string you provide

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` looks at the first element of the format pattern string, `yyyy`, this means 4-digit year. Then it looks at the first element of your date string, `Tue`. `Tue` cannot be a four digit year. Therefore it throws the exception (it probably only needs to look at the `T` to decide).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using old and quite problematic classes, especially [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

For your example, perhaps consider using [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

```
String date = "Tue Jul 03 16:59:51 IST 2018";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, format);
```

Comment: I can’t decide whether I want to recommend `ZonedDateTime` over `LocalDateTime` here. The string includes a time zone abbreviation, so it could be considered a shame to throw it away from the outset. On the other hand, three and four letter time zone abbreviations are generally ambiguous, so if trying to parse it, we risk a result that conflicts with what was intended. `LocalDateTime` evades that problem.

Comment: @OleV.V. Funnily enough I wrote the answer initially with `ZonedDateTime` but edited it to `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your pattern has to match the string you want to parse you need to adjust the pattern as following:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

Infos gathered from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You should also use the new `java.time` API introduced with Java 8.

```
String s = "Tue Jul 03 16:59:51 IST 2018";
//Java 7 way
SimpleDateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date d = newformat.parse(s);
//Java 8 way
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
```